# Python Regex greedy boundaries

Tags: python, regex

I have a

```
import re

s = """
/* comments */
vector<CWaypoint> Vparam;     // comment
int cValue=2049;                // comment
double param=0.01;              // comment
"""

exp = re.compile(r"(?:\s|\b)(.+?)=(.+?)\b;")
print(exp.findall(s))
```

My expected output is

```
[(cValue,2049), (param,0.01)]
```

but why am I getting the data type before the variable name like below

```
[('int cValue', '2049'), ('double param', '0.01')]
```

Why isn't boundaries working even if they are non greedy

Comment: Regex scans from left to right, so they match. You can change your regex from `(.+?)=` to `(\w+)=` to get what you want. (Though I don't think parsing code with regex is a good idea).

Comment: What if I have a special character in the variable name?

Comment: There is the option of using `(\S+)`, which matches non-space characters (again, this is very poor approximation, and you should consult the documentation for the exact character set).

Comment: Whats with "Left to right" ? I mean how does `.` makes so much of a difference?

Comment: Regex engine scans from left to right, so it will find the left most match first, and since `\b.+?=.+?\b;` matches `int cValue=2049`, it is returned as a match. `\S+` or `\w+` basically forces the content before `=` to contain no space, so you only get the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `\s` will also match newline characters and `.+` will match any char including spaces.

I suggest you to use `[^\s=]+` before `=`

```
exp = re.compile(r"([^\s=]+)=(.+?);")
```